# Input String was not in correct format in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

We've been facing an issue while saving our page. It throws "Input String was not in correct format". After trying so many time, we found there was no problem with the code, but with the "Cache (Temporary Internet File"). After Cache was cleared, it saved without any error. Does anyone knew the reason behind it?

Comment: Post your code, and you'll stand a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Yes i would say the same thing as pmarflee said

Comment: I'm sure there is no error in the code. Because it works in all other computers. It works in the same computer after clearing the cache  which threw "Input string error".

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the sort of error that you get from a bad parse, say `Int32.Parse("foo")` where you were expecting `"foo"` to be something like `"123"`.  I am not sure why this would be affected by the cache.

My recommendation would be to look at the method where the exception occurs and see if it attempts to parse a string.  If you expect that the string might not be in the correct format (say, it's a string entered by the user, you can replace

```
int i = Int32.Parse(myString);
```

with

```
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse(myString, out i))
```

Then you can handle the case of bad input in the `else`.

If however you expect the string should always be in the correct format (in other words, this is truly "exceptional" behavior), then I would leave it as a `Parse` and add a `catch (FormatException ex)`, and within the `catch` log the string that caused the exception.  This should hopefully help you in tracking down the underlying cause of the problem.

Or if the problem has never reoccured since you cleared the cache back in October of '09, just chalk it up to cosmic rays and move on I guess. ;)

Comment: Of course this is just a guess; it's hard to be sure without seeing your code.  But this question is currently one of the top Google results for [ASP.Net input string not correct format] and I thought it ought to have an answer, even if the original asker has moved on long ago.